# Aspx pages not get displayed when shifted to new domain

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

Setup:

- windows server 2008 R2
- IIS 7.5
- registered ASP.NET

I have shifted my web application from http://www.mytestsite.ae to http://www.mytestsite.com. **Server & Database are same**. 
But when i browse through my website, only HTML pages display properly. 
On ASPX pages i got `404 : Not Found`.

Someone told me to  add the `.aspx` in MiME type but when
i added the mime type i got a strange response. When i click on that page, instead of opening in browser it starts downloading that page.

Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Comment: In your `web.config` file ensure you have `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>` I had the same issue and after including that in my `web.config` file it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have all the above settings right then you should check your `IIS` settings

- Click on Windows Start Button , in the search box , write `inetmgr` and press Enter
- Go to `IIS`
- `Sites`
- Select Your Site
- In the `Default Website Home Window` double click on `Handler Mappings`
- In the `Actions Pane`, click on `Revert To Parent`
- Press `Restart` and check your website